# Difference between including iife directly in Head section vs. including iife in shared.js file also in Head

Tags: javascript, iife

What differences would there be between including an arbitrary javascript IIFE wrapped in a script tag in the Head section of every page of a website versus including the very same IIFE in a shared.js file, also on all pages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - inline vs external script - what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918246/javascript-inline-vs-external-script-whats-the-difference)

Comment: Yes, thank you it does